# Subclassed UISegmentedControl does not respond to "setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment"

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, subclassing

I need to style UISegmentedControl in various ways, and therefore made a subclass:

```
@interface MYSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
@end
```

I can style my control using [[MYSegmentedControl appearance]...], and everything seems to work just fine (setting selected segment, titles etc.) except from the fact that I can not disable segments in MYSegmentedControl.

Looking at the code snippet below, segment 0 of both my *segway and *segwayTwo should be disabled. However this is only the case for *segwayTwo - all segments are enabled for my *segway, which is simply a subclass of UISegmentedControl.

```
MYSegmentedControl *segway = [[MYSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
[segway insertSegmentWithTitle:@"A" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segway insertSegmentWithTitle:@"B" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segway insertSegmentWithTitle:@"C" atIndex:2 animated:NO];

segway.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[segway setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segway setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[segway setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:2];

[myTableCell addSubview:segway];

UISegmentedControl *segwayTwo = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 10, 100, 30)];
[segwayTwo insertSegmentWithTitle:@"X" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segwayTwo insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Y" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segwayTwo insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Z" atIndex:2 animated:NO];

segwayTwo.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[segwayTwo setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segwayTwo setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[segwayTwo setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:2];

[myTableCell addSubview:segwayTwo];
```

Does anybody have a clue why "setEnabled:NO ..." apparently is suppressed for MYSegmentedControl, and can you figure out at way to make it behave like an "ordinary" UISegmentedControl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you just call `segwayXX.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;` and not the setEnabled?  Selected and enabled are very different.

Comment: I just changed my sample to reflect the fact, that I can set a selectedSegment in both cases, and that I'd like my segment 0 to be disabled, and segment 1 and 2 to be enabled. However, setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0 only works for *segwayTwo, and not my *segway control. And I need to be able to both set selectedSegment AND to disable some of my segments!

Comment: When you setEnabled:NO, I believe you make them unclickable.  Therefore, the user can NOT enable them by touching.  You can have only have 1 or 0 selected segments at a time.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that my segment 0 on the *segway control do not become unclickable, even though I specify setEnabled:NO, whereas it works as expected for the segwayTwo control. Why don't the two controls behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

```
  //this should solve

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
     [segwayTwo setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
     [segwayTwo setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
     [segwayTwo setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:2];
  });
```